# Camera pitching issue unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-camera, pinchzoom

I have this code and it's giving me this error on some fields. Can anyone give me a solution please?

Assets\Scripts\CameraController.cs(46,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Camera.isOrthoGraphic'

Assets\Scripts\CameraController.cs(49,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Camera.orthographicSize'

Assets\Scripts\CameraController.cs(57,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Camera.fieldOfView'

CODE:

public float perspectiveZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the field of view in perspective mode.
    public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the orthographic size in orthographic mode.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (GameManager.GameIsOver)
    {
        this.enabled = false;
        return;
    }

    // If there are two touches on the device...
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        // If the camera is orthographic...
        if (**Camera.isOrthoGraphic**)
        {
            // ... change the orthographic size based on the change in distance between the touches.
            **Camera.orthographicSize** += deltaMagnitudeDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;

            // Make sure the orthographic size never drops below zero.
            **Camera.orthographicSize** = Mathf.Max(**Camera.orthographicSize**, 0.1f);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise change the field of view based on the change in distance between the touches.
            **Camera.fieldOfView** += deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed;

            // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
            **Camera.fieldOfView** = Mathf.Clamp(**Camera.fieldOfView**, 0.1f, 179.9f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the main camera instance add the field

```
public Camera cam;
```

And access with `cam.IsOrtographic`

Make sure you link it in the editor to your camera

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **Camera.xxxxx** with your own instanced camera in your scene, for example:

- Camera.main.isOrthoGraphic
- Camera.main.orthographicSize
- Camera.main.fieldOfView.